# Java IntelliJ GUI Designer - How can I: change the window title bar and system menu icon, and go to another form when button is pressed

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea, designer

I'm currently learning IntelliJ's GUI designer but I'm struggling to find documentation or any guides. So far I have watch a fantastic introductory youtube series from [a guy called Scott Couprie](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3Esa3e6Kj9rds7CSXzKVTsXVL0VGZTRq), which I really recommend to any complete beginners reading this.

I would like to do three things. If anybody has a link to documentation or guides that'd be great.

1. Change the window title bar text.

**EDIT**: I have now discovered this can be changed with ***setTitle("Title")***.

[image]

2. Change the system menu icon. I am using MacOS so I don't even see an icon in the preview, so I'm not even sure where the icon goes.
   **EDIT:** while I can't confirm this is working due to using MacOS, I see that you can use the following in the constructor:

   ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("images/16x16.png");
   setIconImage(img.getImage());
3. Be able to click a button and go to another form. So far I have been able to switch panels after pressing a button, but only to other panels within the same form itself.

Thanks.

I have tried searching for related documentation or youtube videos but I'm not sure what terms to search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be changed with:

```
setTitle("Whatever you want the title to say");
```